# Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, group-by

This is the code:

```
PRICE <- as.vector(my.data[,"PRICE"])
ADDRESS_CITY_NAME <- as.vector(my.data[,"ADDRESS_CITY_NAME"])

my.data <- data.frame(ADDRESS_CITY_NAME,log(UNITS), log(PRICE))

my.data %>%
  +group_by(ADDRESS_CITY_NAME)%>%
  +do(tidy(lm(UNITS~PRICE, data=my.data))
```

The data I used (part of it):

```
287      INDEPENDENCE  4.1108739  0.42526774
288      INDEPENDENCE  4.1431347  0.47000363
289      INDEPENDENCE  4.2766661  0.17395331
290      INDEPENDENCE  4.0604430  0.46373402
291          LOVELAND  4.3820266  0.38526240
292          LOVELAND  4.2626799  0.42526774
293          LOVELAND  4.1271344  0.51282363
294          LOVELAND  4.8040210  0.43178242
295          LOVELAND  4.1896547  0.37843644
296          LOVELAND  4.2766661  0.32930375
297          LOVELAND  4.4543473  0.39204209
298          LOVELAND  4.3820266  0.39877612
299          LOVELAND  3.7841896  0.43178242
```

I keep getting the error: 
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :    no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Answer (score 2):

It is in the `data.frame` creation step where the column names got changed

```
my.data <- data.frame(ADDRESS_CITY_NAME,log(UNITS), log(PRICE))
```

Instead, it would be

```
my.data <- data.frame(ADDRESS_CITY_NAME,UNITS = log(UNITS), PRICE = log(PRICE))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @new_R  I see a `+` i.e. `+group_by(ADDRESS_CITY_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

I used part of your data and played with the newer dplyr 0.8.3 syntax

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, broom)

my.data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ADDRESS_CITY_NAME,    ~UNITS,     ~PRICE,
      "INDEPENDENCE", 4.1108739, 0.42526774,
      "INDEPENDENCE", 4.1431347, 0.47000363,
      "INDEPENDENCE", 4.2766661, 0.17395331,
      "INDEPENDENCE",  4.060443, 0.46373402,
          "LOVELAND", 4.3820266,  0.3852624,
          "LOVELAND", 4.2626799, 0.42526774,
          "LOVELAND", 4.1271344, 0.51282363,
          "LOVELAND",  4.804021, 0.43178242,
          "LOVELAND", 4.1896547, 0.37843644,
          "LOVELAND", 4.2766661, 0.32930375,
          "LOVELAND", 4.4543473, 0.39204209,
          "LOVELAND", 4.3820266, 0.39877612,
          "LOVELAND", 3.7841896, 0.43178242
  )
```

Then I used syntax found here for new functions making it easier to apply a function for each group.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html

The following syntax will fit lm oneach group and return a table with coefficients and p values:

```
my.data %>%
  group_by(ADDRESS_CITY_NAME)%>%
  group_modify(~ tidy(lm(log(UNITS) ~ log(PRICE), data=.x)))
```

Returns the desired result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   ADDRESS_CITY_NAME [2]
  ADDRESS_CITY_NAME term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>             <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 INDEPENDENCE      (Intercept)   1.38      0.0139    98.9   0.000102
2 INDEPENDENCE      log(PRICE)   -0.0426    0.0125    -3.40  0.0767  
3 LOVELAND          (Intercept)   1.37      0.179      7.68  0.000118
4 LOVELAND          log(PRICE)   -0.0902    0.197     -0.457 0.662
```

Another way to model on grouped data is nesting the groups. Here I would like to use all the three broom functions and not repeat the fitting:

Credit goes to this magnicent blog: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups

```
broomed <- my.data %>%
  nest(-ADDRESS_CITY_NAME)%>%
  mutate(fit=map(data, ~ lm(log(UNITS) ~ log(PRICE), data = .)),
         glanced = map(fit, glance),
         augmented = map(fit, augment),
         tidied = map(fit,tidy))


broomed %>% unnest(glanced)

broomed %>% unnest(augmented) 

broomed %>% unnest(tidied)
```